# JSF SelectOneMenuItem onselect attribute

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2

I have created selectOneMenuItem(JSF).I placed my events on valueChangeListener / onchange like that

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="ddl" value="#{Foo.attr}"
                onchange="submit()"
                valueChangeListener="#{Foo.renderFoo}">
```

When I select one vlaue from selectOneMenuItem then event fires.Now when I reselect that value ,then event doesn't fire (because this is the `valueChangeListener` event) so it doesn't fire.I want that event should fire on every selection even on again the same selection.I found `onselect` but unable to find that is it right and how can i use this `onselect`.Anyu help would be greatly appreciable

Comment: *"even on again the same selection"* ??? rethink your design , you better fire event on every change (using `f:ajax`) , and might consider a refresh button , but to fire an event *"even on again the same selection"* ???

Answer (score 0):

You can use click ajax event as a separate listener like this.

```html
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.value}">

    <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{bean.onClick}"/>

    <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="A"/>
    <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="B"/>
    <f:selectItem itemValue="3" itemLabel="C"/>

</h:selectOneMenu>
```